# CSS attribute selector class starts with but not equals to

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply css to all class that starts with for example 'abcd-' but I don't want to apply that css to class with name for example 'abcd-dontapply'. Can I do this?

What I tried

```
 a[class |= "abcd"] :not([class = "abcd-dontapply"])
 {
     ---define CSS 
 }
```

But this is not working, it is not applying CSS to any class that starts with 'abcd-'.

Comment: Don't add whitespace unnecessarily. The whitespace just before the `:not` is significant, i.e. it changes the meaning of the selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in your question:

> Don't add whitespace unnecessarily. The whitespace just before the
>   :not is significant, i.e. it changes the meaning of the selector.

---

```
a[class^="abcd"]:not(.abcd-dontapply)
{
    /* define CSS here*/
}
```

You can find all attribute selectors specifications [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with proper css selectors:
starts with selector would be like-

```
div[class^="abc"]:not([class="abc2"])
```

I have a sample jsfiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/8w65ffj0/1/